# Searching objects in a list

Tags: vb.net, predicate

I have a list of objects, and I want to search it to see if myobject.articleID matches a given articleID. From what I've gather using .Find(Of T) is the best way to go about this, however I am having some difficulty implementing it. Here's some code I have so far:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function SetTagOnFavorite(ByVal articleID As Integer, ByVal tagtext As String, ByVal mobileGUID As String) As AddTagResult
    Dim result As New AddTagResult
    Dim userID As Long = GetUserIDByMobileGUID(mobileGUID)


    If userID > 0 Then
        Dim pageNum As Integer = 1
        Dim pageLen As Integer = 500 'arbitrarily large number
        Dim savedArticleList As New List(Of SimpleArticle)
        savedArticleList = GetSavedArticles(mobileGUID, pageNum, pageLen)

        If savedArticleList.Find(Function( m As SimpleArticle) m.articleID = articleID)


            Dim lq As New lqDFDataContext
            Dim var = lq.web_AddTagToArticle(userID, articleID, tagtext).ToList()

            If var.Any() Then
                Dim vRes = var.First()
                result.articletagID = vRes.articletagID
                result.newarticletag = vRes.newarticletag
                result.newusertag = vRes.newusertag
                result.usertagID = vRes.usertagID
                result.resultinfo = "Success."

            End If
       End If  
    Else
        result.resultinfo = STR_NoUserIDMostLikelyTheSessionTimedOut
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

The error I get is, "value of type SimpleArticle cannot be converted to Boolean".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Find(Of` returns the found object, you need to change this line:

```
If savedArticleList.Find(Function( m As SimpleArticle) m.articleID = articleID)
```

to

```
If savedArticleList.Find(Function( m As SimpleArticle) m.articleID = articleID) IsNot Nothing
```

or if you need the found item, store the result of `Find` in a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

You could optimize @competent_tech's answer further as:

```
If savedArticleList.Any(Function(m) m.articleID = articleID))
```